# Need help setting up custom code for chatbox widget on Twitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitch

I am trying to get a typewriter effect but emotes don't show up, long text doesn't wrap either. Feel free to ask more details I don't know if you need more info. Any help is appreciated.
I am trying to get a typewriter effect but emotes don't show up, long text doesn't wrap either. Feel free to ask more details I don't know if you need more info. Any help is appreciated.

Page is [streamlabs](https://streamlabs.com/dashboard#/chatbox) you may need a twitch account
HTML Code

```
<!-- item will be appened to this layout -->
<div id="log" class="sl__chat__layout">
</div>
 
<!-- chat item -->
<script type="text/template" id="chatlist_item">
  <div data-from="{from}" data-id="{messageId}">
    <span class="meta" style="color: {color}">
      <span class="badges">
      </span>
      <span class="name">{from}</span>
    </span>
 
    <span id="message">
      {message}
    </span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Css Code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Codystar&display=swap');
 
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
body {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000;
    background: {background_color};
        font-family: 'Codystar', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: {font_size};
    line-height: 1.5em;
  color: {text_color};
}
 
#log>div {
    animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
}
 
.colon {
    display: none;
}
 
#log {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
 
#log>div {
    display: table-row;
}
 
#log>div.deleted {
    visibility: hidden;
}
 
#log .emote {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
}
 
#log .emote img {
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
}
 
#log .message,#log .meta {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
}
 
#log .meta {
    width: 35%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
#log .message {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 65%;
}
#message {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 65%;
}
 
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -0.1em;
}
 
.name {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {
    // obj will be empty for chat widget
    // this will fire only once when the widget loads
});
 
document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
    // obj will contain information about the event
e++  
typeEffect(e);
 
 
 
 
});
var speed = 50;
var e = 1;
function typeEffect(inp) {
  var o = inp;
  document.getElementById("message").id= "message"+o;
    var text = $("#message"+o).text();
    $("#message"+o).text('');
    var i = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(i < text.length) {
            $("#message"+o).append(text.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById("message").id= "complete";
        };
  }, speed);
 
 
    }
```

Comment: please dont repeat your text to make to post the question.

it needs more explanation on what you have tried and what does the code actually do.

Comment: you can make use of snippet if you want to add some code to make it visual.